# Filter list in Raw Django

Tags: python, django

I have this query but It didn't filter the specific index. I just want to filter the paid_by column based on the emp_list, that's why I've come up with this indexes `paid_by = emp[1]`.it would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing thing wrong. thank you so much in advance.

> TypeError: 'Person' object does not support indexing

```
emp_list = Person.objects.raw('SELECT id,paid_by, IF(paid = "Yes" || paid = "YES", "paid", "unpaid") as id,paid, category, category_status, count(paid)  FROM app_person  WHERE paid_by != "" GROUP BY paid_by, paid, category, category_status ORDER BY paid_by,paid ')

for emp in emp_list:
        paid_by = emp[1] #I want to filter paid_by in emp_list
        print(paid_by)
```

Answer (score 1):

`paid_by = emp[1]` will be an instance of `Person` and you should be able to access `emp.paid_by` if that is a field of your model. If fields names aren't the same you could set the mapping of the query fields to your model fields https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#mapping-query-fields-to-model-fields

Answer (score 1):

Your `Person.objects.raw(...)` query returns queryset  of `Person` objects, so when you iterate over them and do `emp[1]` you're trying use indexing on Person object, which is impossible and cause `TypeError: 'Person' object does not support indexing`.

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, since you typed `I just want to filter the paid_by column based on the emp_list`, but paid_by is a field of Person, and emp_list is a queryset of Persons, so literally you're saying that you're trying to filter paid_by column based on set of Persons, which does not make any sense. Please update your post with more details about what you're trying to achiveve.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I just want to filter all the list or names under paid_by column, it is possible? need help

Comment: If you want to filter your db records by paid_by column, you can do following: `Person.objects.filter(paid_by='your value')`. If you want to exclude something from selection, you can use following: `Person.objects.exclude(paid_by="")`. Is that what you need?